# Why does Youtube use Insecure RTMP, considering that Facebook uses secure RTMPS?

Tags: security, video-streaming, network-security, rtmps, application-security

RTMP being an insecure unencrypted protocol, suffers from attacks like MITM and network sniffing. Naturally so, FB uses RTMPS: https://ppc.land/streaming-facebook-moves-live-videos-completely-to-rtmps/

Why is Google lackluster about adopting this secure approach? Is it due to less compatibility for the RTMPS protocol with streaming software and providers?

Azure does not provide RTMPS, at least their official developer doc does not mention that.

Answer (score 0):

RTMPS was never an official standard. Adobe has a custom encryption called RTMPE, but that was never really supported outside Adobe software.

Because RTMPS is not official most high end video equipment and a lot of server software does not support it.

Comment: Thank you @szatmary. Understood!